# How can I replace one Placeholder Word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I had an Placeholder, it's named **{{inactive}}**.

**{{inactive}}** is in my HTML a checkbox.

it have 2 outputs, one output is "**true**" and the other output is "**false**"

Now I will replace this, because when I do an wkhtmltoPdf.exe task, then are in my PDF the word true or false, but I need: **not given or are given.**

Here is an Sample, but it not works:

```
<script>
    inact = true;
</script>
<tr style="height:58pt">
    <td id="test" align="right">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(inact)
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>

function myFunction() {
    var testing;
    if (inact = true) {
        testing = "are given";
    } else {
        testing = "not given"; //else = not true (false) 
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testing;
}
```

Comment: _"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. <...>"_ Please place your code in the question itself. Don't cheat the system by placing a jsfiddle link in a code block. The warning message you got is there for a reason.

Comment: finish, I have place the code here.

Comment: keep the fiddle link, live demos are always helpful

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/hoLnmbtv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Missing script tags around function
- Single equals in if statement
- You are not calling the function anywhere

The following is a tweaked version of your code:

```
<tr style="height:58pt">
    <td id="test" align="right"></td>
</tr>

<script>
    inact = true;

    function myFunction() {
        var testing;
        if (inact == true) {
            testing = "are given";
        } else {
            testing = "not given";
        }
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testing;
    }

    myFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: i need this for an <td> not for an span, I cant set in there an ID

Comment: Ok, I have swapped the span back for your original code. As long as the ID is the same it wont matter what the element is. One more point a <tr> needs to be inside a <table> for it to render properly.

Comment: As I said, you need to wrap a <tr> in a <table> for it to render. http://jsfiddle.net/hoLnmbtv/2/

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this like below:

your HTML Should be:

```
<script>
 inact = false;
</script>
<body onload="myFunction();">
<table>
<tr style="height:58pt">
  <td id="test" align="right">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(inact)
    </script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</body>
```

Your JS Should BE:

```
function myFunction() {
var testing;
if (inact == true) {
    testing = "are given";
} else {
    testing = "not given"; //else = not true (false) 
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testing;
}
```

now you will get the proper result.

Comment: There is a single equals in the if statement meaning it will always  be true.

Comment: @FlabbyRabbit ya i just correct, i forgot while typing. Thanks